# How can i search events by description field using Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to list all upcoming events for a given artist. Unfortunately, the query that i use:`/search?type=event&fields=name,description,place&q=artist-name` does not list all available events. It only lists the events for which the keyword "artist-name" match the field "name". To display all available events, the query must look into the "description" field in addition to the "name". How can i make such a query ?

Comment: There is no way to do that

Comment: Thanks for quick reply @WizKid. I hope Facebook will improve the search API. Maybe you can do something about it ^^